# Why is the default value 0x1000 instead of 0x200?

Tags: binary

[Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi7U1.png)

From the manual , in Bits 12-8 , the default value is 0x10 , meaning that only Bit 9 is 1.
From the calculator it shows `b10 0000 0000 = 0x200`. But why does the document say its `0x1000` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each hexadecimal digit corresponds to **4 bits** (a.k.a. a *nibble*). In the number 0x10, only bit **5** is 1.

The correct conversion is this:

```
0x10 -->    1    0
         0001 0000 --> 0b10000
```

Comment: Thanks , but I wonder why developers don't specify it as a default value of '10000' instead

Comment: @Arkyo The number can be written as "binary 10000" or "decimal 16" or "octal 20" or "hexadecimal 10"... They're all equally valid. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ The documentation author chose hexadecimal.